# res.render passed objects, what are they called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have been struggling all the time with these objects inside res.render, how can i define them globally or somehow outside of res.render? I hope there is a way to do so.. here is an example:

```
router.get("/home/blog", function(req,res){
    Sandwich.find({}, function(err,posts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);         
        } else {          
                res.render("blog", {posts:posts} <--------- These )            
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is not clear what are your trying to do.

Comment: I just want to know what this {object: object} is called?

Answer (score 0):

> res.render passed objects, what are they called?

It's just an argument passed to the template renderer.  The [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) for `res.render()` calls it a ***"locals object"***.  Here's what the doc shows"

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])

locals, an object whose properties define local variables for the view.
```

> how can i define them globally or somehow outside of res.render?

You would generally not define them globally as each template you render should have a unique set of data that it uses in order to render the page.  If you have portions of your template that are literally the same for every single user on your server, you could create a shared object (not a global) that you import into any of your route files and then put that shared object into your locals object that you pass to the renderer as a property.  Globals are not recommended for that kind of use.

In the specific route you show, you can't put the posts into a global or even a shared object because as people add/remove posts, that global or shared object would not get updated.

FYI, when you get an error querying your database, you still need to send a response to the request, perhaps a 5xx status response or render an error page.

Comment: Thank you for the response, If I   want to include more than one, it doesn't work, because one renders before the other, example :

router.get("/home/blog", function(req,res){
    Post.find({}, function(err,posts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);         
        } else {          
                res.render("blog", {posts:posts})            
        }

    News.find({}, function(err,news){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      } else {
         res.render("blog", {news:news})
      }
    });

I tried this but whatever is first only works, any fix?

Comment: @EliasNaf - You can only send ONE response per request so, in line with that, you can only call `res.render()` once per response.  If your question is really how to do you solve the problem with two separate asynchronous calls that are needed to render the page, you should open a new question that states that as the question and shows your specific code example.  That's easy to solve using the promise interface for the database and `Promise.all()`, but that is not at all what you asked here so you should ask about that in a new question.  Did I answer your original question?

Comment: @EliasNaf - If you post a new question, drop me a comment here with a link to that question and I'll go have a look at the new question.

Answer (score 0):

That object is an ***object literal***. For the purpose of the example you have provided there are two possible ways for an object to be passed inside `res.render`

1. { obj }

```
const obj = req.body
res.render('success',{obj})
```

2. { obj : obj }   // like you already have it

---

> how can i define them globally or somehow outside of res.render?

You must know the object passed into the response `res.render` It's already globally accesible in the scope of this response.

If you have requirements that not fit into this, It's possible to extend with `res.locals`

##### res.locals (Properties)

From [Express Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) 4.x API

Scoped to the request, available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user
  res.locals.authenticated = !req.user.anonymous
  next()
})
```